# How to protect a controller from accessing parent and root directories from user input

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, controller, security

I have an ASP.Net MVC controller action that is designed to give access to specific files in select directories and sub-directories in my App_Data folder.

Will someone tell me how to lock this down so that users cannot access root or parent directories and only the files in the directory and sub-directories?

Here's the insecure version of the controller action:

```
public string GetFile(string fileName)
{
    string dataDir = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetData("DataDirectory").ToString();
    string specialFiles = "SpecialFiles";

    string finalPath = Path.Combine(dataDir, specialFiles, fileName);
    string text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(finalPath);
    return text;
}
```

The naive solution would be to check `fileName` for string combinations like `..\`, and then throw an exception or something. And while I can implement this solution, I would prefer to follow a best practice if one exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before combining the strings into a finalPath, extract the FileName from `fileName` as below:

```
fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(fileName)
```

Comment: This will work for files in the active directory, but not in sub-directories